# iPython won't let me finish defining a function

Tags: python, ipython

I want to define a function with multiple lines in it. But ipython seems to be considering a function complete as early as possible.

```
$ ipython
In [1]: def whatever():
   ...:     a = 1

In [2]:
```

How do I make ipython work like it used to, like,

```
$ ipython
In [1]: def whatever():
   ...:     a = 1
   ...:     print(a)
   ...:

In [2]:
```

I'm using Python 3.6, iPython --version 7.0.1, and Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I believe the problem was fixed in 7.1.0; you should update your iPython: `pip install --upgrade ipython`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ahh... that's good news... I had that this on 7.0.1 and had to downgrade to the last 6.x to get stuff done... Wasted a good 20 minutes trying to work out what the heck was going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@daniel-roseman is right, I just needed to upgrade from iPython version 7.0.1 to 7.1.1. For me that was running the command

```
pipenv --update ipython
```